# Nginx doesn't serve CSS

Tags: command-line, server, nginx

this is my current Nginx config and my problem is the 404 page doesn't serve the CSS, it serves the CSS if i put the CSS files into `/var/www/testdoamincom`, but it doesn't server in any other case, is there any way to keep my `404error` page and it's `CSS` files separate from my other website files but still get the CSS?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; 
    server_name test.domain.com;
    root /var/www/testdoamincom;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # SSL Configuration Start
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cloudflare_mydomain.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/cloudflare_mydomain.com.pem;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/origin-pull-ca.pem;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    # SSL Configuration End  

    # Error Pages Start
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 400 401 402 403 404 405 406 407 408 409 410 411 412 413 414 415 416 417 418 421 422 423 424 425 426 428 429 431 451 500 501 502 503 504 505 506 507 508 510 511 /404.html;

    location = /404.html {
        root /var/www/html;
    } 
    # Error Pages End

    location ~ \.php$ {
         include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the fix;

```
location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {
    root /path/to/your/css/files;
    expires 30d;
}
```